# Get pressed mouse-button withous AWT or SWING component?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Is there a way to obtain mouse-button status (if they are pressed or not) when I am not using any Swing or AWT components?

So far I have something like this:

```
while(true) {
    Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    //mouse movement
    if (point.x != prevX || point.y != prevY) {
        prevX = point.x;
        prevY = point.y;
        try {
            //do sth here with the movement
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use `MouseAdapter` somehow even without Swing `JFrame` etc?

Comment: It would require natives.  What is this app., some kind of logger?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, app for controling mouse via network - movement and clicks on one PC would do the same on another pc in the network...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Java is not the best language for that type of functionality.  It would require access to the system event queue at a lower level than Java offers.  So ..look to supply natives for each platform of interest, for that feature.